# Using VBA how to make a button that creates a folder and names that folder by the content of 2 cells which have dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am new to VBA. 
Using VBA in Excel how to make a button that creates a folder and names that folder by the content of 2 cells with date content. This seems impossible!!

Answer (score 0):

*You may use this VBA code, will create New Folder and also add current Date & Time with the Folder Name.*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim startPath As String
    Dim myName1 As String


    startPath = "Your File Path here\"
    myName1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Text


    Dim folderPathWithName As String
    folderPathWithName = startPath & Application.PathSeparator & myName1 & " " & Format$(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & " " & Format$(Time, "hh-mm-ss")

    If Dir(folderPathWithName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        MkDir folderPathWithName
    Else
       MsgBox "Folder already exists"
       Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- From **D**eveloper TAB click **D**esign Mode then **I**nsert.
- Under **A**ctiveX Controls click **C**ommand button Icon and draw button on the Sheet.
- **D**ouble click the Button to open VB editor.
- Then **C**opy & **P**aste code lines between,

**P**rivate Sub CommandButton1_Click()

**E**nd Sub.

- **S**ave code & return to the Sheet, click **D**esign Mode to exit.
- Finally Click the **C**ommand button to **R**UN the **M**acro.

**N.B.**

- *In this `myName1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Text`, cell reference `A1` is editable.*
- *For variable `startPath =` replace text `Your File Path here\"` with path where you want to create New Folder, for example it should be like,, `startPath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\"`.*

Comment: I tried this and it does not work. It gives me this error. Run-time error '76': Path not found. Also I want to use 2 dates like a pay period as a folder name. Like 09-16-2019 To 09-22-2019. These two dates are already in 2 cells automatically changing every week. This is the setup. In cell a1 I put =TODAY()    In cell a2 I put =CEILING(a1+1,7)-19 AND in cell a3 I put  =CEILING(a1+1,7)-13   . Now I want a code that creates a folder with the dates of cell a2 and a3 . Thank you for helping out:)

Comment: @yemen,, replace this `"Your File Path here\"` with your file path like `C:\myfolder\`,,  here the code will create `New Folder`,, and remember File Path must be correct one!!

Comment: I did that but it still does not work. I get it to work with a date but not with the two dates in cells a2 and a3 as mentioned above. I don't know why but i searched everywhere on the internet and it seems nobody has the answer to this. I can send you the excel sheet if you like. But the setup is as mentioned above in the previous reply.

Comment: @yemen, Ok ,, find my Mail Id with profile & send me the file,, I'll do it for you ☺